# How to iterate over a column with list of lists as values and create a new column

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark

I have a dataframe with values like

```
+---------+---------+---------+---------+----------+----------+----------+
| column1 | column2 | column3 | column4 | column 6 | column 7 | column 8 |
+---------+---------+---------+---------+----------+----------+----------+
| a       | b       |       1 | c       |        2 |        3 |        4 |
| a       | b       |       4 | z       |        5 |        6 |        7 |
| x       | y       |       1 | c       |        2 |        3 |        4 |
| x       | y       |       4 | z       |        5 |        6 |        7 |
+---------+---------+---------+---------+----------+----------+----------+
```

The rows are then grouped on the basis of column1 and column2 and then aggregated in a new column agg_data

```
+---------+---------+-----------------------+---------+
| column1 | column2 |       agg_data        | column4 |
+---------+---------+-----------------------+---------+
| a       | b       | [[1,2,3,4],[4,5,6,7]] | c       |
| x       | y       | [[1,2,3,4],[4,5,6,7]] | z       |
+---------+---------+-----------------------+---------+
```

The data inside the agg_data are actually "Row" objects that were grouped on the basis of column1 and column2 and then were aggregated into a single column.

I need to iterate over the values in agg_data, get the "column 7" data from the list of all the row stored, concatenate it and add a new column to the data frame.
Something like this.

```
+---------+---------+-----------------------+---------+------------+
| column1 | column2 |       agg_data        | column4 | agg_values |
+---------+---------+-----------------------+---------+------------+
| a       | b       | [[1,2,3,4],[4,5,6,7]] | c       |        3,6 |
| x       | y       | [[1,2,3,4],[4,5,6,7]] | z       |        3,6 |
+---------+---------+-----------------------+---------+------------+
```

I am new to scala, hence I dont have much idea how to approach this.
Though, I have tried few suggestions from Stack Overflow
like this one [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59238884/scala-spark-how-to-get-first-elements-of-all-sub-arrays) here. But that didnt work as expected.
It included all the values in the table in a single row.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using **Spark 3.0** you can use transform function as below

```
df.withColumn("agg_values", transform($"column3", arr => element_at(arr, -2)))
```

FOR **Spark2.4+**

```
df.withColumn("agg_values", expr("transform(column3, x -> element_at(x, -2) )"))
```

If you want to convert the added new array as string you can use `concat_ws`

Output:

```
+-------+-------+------------------------------------------+-------+---------+
|column1|column2|column3                                   |column4|agg_values|
+-------+-------+------------------------------------------+-------+---------+
|a      |b      |[[1, 2, 3, 4], [4, 5, 6, 7], [7, 8, 9, 0]]|c      |[3, 6, 9]|
|x      |y      |[[1, 2, 3, 4], [4, 5, 6, 7], [7, 8, 9, 0]]|z      |[3, 6, 9]|
+-------+-------+------------------------------------------+-------+---------+
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer @koiralo. I am actually seeking for a way to access the value via column name. My question was not clear before I suppose. I have updated it. Could you please advice how can I use the column name to get the data instead of relying on the position.

Comment: can you share the schema of agg_data?

Comment: Take a look at your schema and you can access as `df2.withColumn("newCol", transform($"agg_data", arr => arr("column7")))`

Comment: Sorry, I didnt get what you are asking by schema of agg_data. Also, I am not working on Spark 3.0. hence I am not able to get transform() in withColumn()

Comment: what version of spark are you using? can you share the schema of your dataframe after aggregation?

Answer (score 0):

pyspark solution, but can be adapted to scala also:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql.types import *
tst = sqlContext.createDataFrame([('a','b',[[1,2,3,4],[4,5,6,7],[7,8,9,0]]),('x','y',[[1,2,3,4],[4,5,6,7],[7,8,9,0]])],schema=['column1','column2','column3'])
tst1 = tst.withColumn("flattened",F.flatten('column3'))
#%% generate position  there may be better python ways to do this
pos=[]
ini=2
for x in range(3):# 3 is for this example
    pos+=[ini]
    ini=ini+4
#%%
expr=[F.col('flattened')[x] for x in pos]
tst2 = tst1.withColumn("result",F.array(*expr))
```

Results:

```
+-------+-------+--------------------+--------------------+---------+
|column1|column2|             column3|           flattened|   result|
+-------+-------+--------------------+--------------------+---------+
|      a|      b|[[1, 2, 3, 4], [4...|[1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5...|[3, 6, 9]|
|      x|      y|[[1, 2, 3, 4], [4...|[1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5...|[3, 6, 9]|
+-------+-------+--------------------+--------------------+---------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Check below code.

```
scala> df.show(false)
+-------+-------+------------------------------------------+-------+
|column1|column2|column3                                   |column4|
+-------+-------+------------------------------------------+-------+
|a      |b      |[[1, 2, 3, 4], [4, 5, 6, 7], [7, 8, 9, 0]]|c      |
|x      |y      |[[1, 2, 3, 4], [4, 5, 6, 7], [7, 8, 9, 0]]|z      |
+-------+-------+------------------------------------------+-------+
```

**UDF**

```
scala> val mkString = udf((data:Seq[Seq[Int]]) => data.map(_.init.last).mkString(","))
```

**Result**

```
scala> df.withColumn("agg_values",mkString($"column3")).show(false)
+-------+-------+------------------------------------------+-------+----------+
|column1|column2|column3                                   |column4|agg_values|
+-------+-------+------------------------------------------+-------+----------+
|a      |b      |[[1, 2, 3, 4], [4, 5, 6, 7], [7, 8, 9, 0]]|c      |3,6,9     |
|x      |y      |[[1, 2, 3, 4], [4, 5, 6, 7], [7, 8, 9, 0]]|z      |3,6,9     |
+-------+-------+------------------------------------------+-------+----------+
```

**Without UDF - Spark 2.4+**

```
scala> 

df
.withColumn("agg_values",expr("concat_ws(',',flatten(transform(column3, x -> slice(x,-2,1))))"))
.show(false)

+-------+-------+------------------------------------------+-------+----------+
|column1|column2|column3                                   |column4|agg_values|
+-------+-------+------------------------------------------+-------+----------+
|a      |b      |[[1, 2, 3, 4], [4, 5, 6, 7], [7, 8, 9, 0]]|c      |3,6,9     |
|x      |y      |[[1, 2, 3, 4], [4, 5, 6, 7], [7, 8, 9, 0]]|z      |3,6,9     |
+-------+-------+------------------------------------------+-------+----------+
```

```
scala> 

df
.withColumn("agg_values",expr("concat_ws(',',transform(column3, x -> element_at(x,-2)))"))
.show(false)

+-------+-------+------------------------------------------+-------+----------+
|column1|column2|column3                                   |column4|agg_values|
+-------+-------+------------------------------------------+-------+----------+
|a      |b      |[[1, 2, 3, 4], [4, 5, 6, 7], [7, 8, 9, 0]]|c      |3,6,9     |
|x      |y      |[[1, 2, 3, 4], [4, 5, 6, 7], [7, 8, 9, 0]]|z      |3,6,9     |
+-------+-------+------------------------------------------+-------+----------+
```

Comment: could you please explain "_.init.last" part.

Comment: for example ```Seq(1,2,3,4).init``` output is ```Seq(1,2,3)``` & when call ```last``` mehtod on this you will get value ```3```.

Comment: So I also have an option to access the value using the column name as the position of the value might change. Basically somewhat like this transform(column3, x -> x("required_col"). Can I use the column name in quotes using the '\' in expression?

Comment: what is this ```required_col``` ? is it number or column ??

Comment: Its a column name. Actually in one part of the code I found this being used column3(0)("required_column"). This returns the value in the column "required_column" for the first element. So the same way can I use the column name to get the value instead of depending on the position?

Comment: in question i don't see other columns inside ```column3``` column.. can you post some sample data in question & printSchem ?

Answer (score 0):

**`spark>=2.4`**

```scala
  val df = spark.sql("select array(array(1,2,3,4),array(4,5,6,7),array(7,8,9,0)) as column3")
    df.show(false)
    df.printSchema()

    /**
      * +------------------------------------------+
      * |column3                                   |
      * +------------------------------------------+
      * |[[1, 2, 3, 4], [4, 5, 6, 7], [7, 8, 9, 0]]|
      * +------------------------------------------+
      *
      * root
      * |-- column3: array (nullable = false)
      * |    |-- element: array (containsNull = false)
      * |    |    |-- element: integer (containsNull = false)
      */

    df.withColumn("agg_values", expr("TRANSFORM(column3, x -> element_at(x, -2) )"))
      .show(false)

    /**
      * +------------------------------------------+----------+
      * |column3                                   |agg_values|
      * +------------------------------------------+----------+
      * |[[1, 2, 3, 4], [4, 5, 6, 7], [7, 8, 9, 0]]|[3, 6, 9] |
      * +------------------------------------------+----------+
      */
    // use array_join to get string

    df.withColumn("agg_values", expr("TRANSFORM(column3, x -> element_at(x, -2) )"))
      .withColumn("agg_values", array_join(col("agg_values"), ", "))
      .show(false)

    /**
      * +------------------------------------------+----------+
      * |column3                                   |agg_values|
      * +------------------------------------------+----------+
      * |[[1, 2, 3, 4], [4, 5, 6, 7], [7, 8, 9, 0]]|3, 6, 9   |
      * +------------------------------------------+----------+
      */
```